# How to toggle a class in my code, and what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, razor

I have CSHTML code as follows. I need to toggle a class on click, which is given in the below Javascript code.

```
 <div class="accordion bar-heading-padding" id="#accordion2" onclick="getclassofitag(this)">
      <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading datalist" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#@i.Id">
               @*<i class="fa fa-chevron-up table-middle icon-width" aria-hidden="false"></i>*@
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down table-middle icon-width" aria-hidden="true"></i>

               <h1 class="accordion-toggle table-middle">
                  @Html.Raw(@i.Name)
               </h1>
          </div>
          <div id="@i.Id" class=" collapse out">
               <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <img ng-src="@i.ImagePath" alt="logo" class="img-thumbnail img-wrap content-image" />
                    <h1>@Html.Raw(@i.Name)</h1>
                    <h3>@Html.Raw(@i.Title)</h3>
                    <br />
                    @Html.Raw(@i.BioDetail)
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and the Javascript code for toggling class of the `i` element.

```
function getclassofitag(element) {
    iTags = element.getElementsByTagName("i");
    iTags.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-down');
    itags.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-up');
}
```

I want to toggle the classes of the `i` element (<i) on click. What code do I have to write to do that? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Debugging hint: Had you used your browser's debugging tools (or used console.log) you could have seen that `iTags` was array-like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will solve your problem

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-down").removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    });

    $('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an HTMLCollection object which contains a collection of DOM objects.  The collection itself does not have a `.classList` property (like you are trying to do).  That is a property of a DOM element, not the collection object.  Thus, your `iTags` variable does not have a .classList` property on it.

So, you need to iterate the `iTags` HTMLCollection and use `.classList` on each individual DOM element.

```
function getclassofitag(element) {
    var item, iTags = element.getElementsByTagName("i");
    for (var i = 0; i < iTags.length; i++) {
        item = iTags[i];
        item.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-down');
        item.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-up');
    }
}
```

Note: I also declared your iTags variable as a local variable so you aren't using an implicit global (which is a bad practice).